# How to define a value in a pytest script at module level to be used in a fixture?

Tags: python, module, pytest, fixtures

I'm trying to define a string in pytest script using a function at module level (and not directly assigning value to a variable) which will be used in a fixture with scope='module'.
The problem is that when using a function at module level, it's being evaluated during the pytest collect phase - and when running pytest on a folder with a couple of scripts, the fixture uses the last evaluated value.

Is there an other way to set the string at module level, per script?

This is what I have so far, which didn't do the job:

my_script1.py:

```
import env_var as env

env.set_my_string('This string will be used in the module fixture')

test_first():
    # Do stuff
```

conf_test.py:

```
import pytest
import env_var as env

@pytest.fixture(scope='module', autouse=True)
def script_handler():
    txt = env.get_my_string()
    # Use txt
    yield
```

env_var.py:

```
_tmp_str = ''

def set_my_string(in_str)
    _tmp_str = in_str

def get_my_string():
    return _tmp_str
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the tested module in the fixture via the `node` object in the `request` fixture, as well as any variables or functions defined in that module:

*test_1.py*

```py
my_env = "test1var"

test_first():
    pass
```

*test_2.py*

```py
my_env = "test2var"

test_first():
    pass
```

*conftest.py*

```py
@pytest.fixture(scope='module', autouse=True)
def script_handler(request):
    txt = request.node.obj.my_var
    print(txt)
    yield
```

`request.node` provides you with the test node, and `obj` is the module in the case of module level fixture, so you can just access the objects defined in the module via that variable.

To illustrate - if you run this:

```
$python -m pytest -v -s test_dir
```

you can see that the module specific value is used:

```
...
collected 2 items

test_dir/test_1.py::test_first test1var
PASSED
test_dir/test_2.py::test_first test2var
PASSED
```

If for some reason you need to save the module-specific string elsewhere (as stated in the comments), you have to save them per module, for example by using the module name as key:

*env_var.py*

```
my_vars = {}

def set_my_string(name, var):
    my_vars[name] = var

def get_my_string(name):
    return my_vars.get(name, "some_default")
```

*test_1.py*

```
from env_var import set_my_string

set_my_string(__name__, "test1var")

def test_first():
    pass
```

*conftest.py*

```
import pytest

from env_var import get_my_string


@pytest.fixture(scope='module', autouse=True)
def script_handler(request):
    module_name = request.node.obj.__name__
    print(get_my_string(module_name))
    yield
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You wrote that the 'request' fixture also has the functions defined in that module, but I couldn't find them. Do you know when it's hiding?
In addition, I'd prefer to set the string using a function from another module (like env.set_my_string() in my example). Is there a way to do that?

Comment: This would not work - you would essentaillay have one global variable that is overwritten each time you call the function. Is there a reason why you need this? As for the functions - they can be accessed the same way as I showed for the variables (they are all objects, in the end). Not sure what you mean by "finding them".

Comment: Using a variable in module level will force the script writers (not necessarily me) to be familiar with an exact well-known variable name.
And sorry, by "finding them" I meant in PyCharm's debugger. But anyway, it worked as you said so thanks for that.

Comment: The script writers have to know how to set the module level value. This can be done by setting a variable as shown, or overwriting a function, or calling some external method (in case it is implemented to save module specific values), but they _have_ to know that API anyway.

Comment: You're right. How do I implement an external method which saves module specific values (as in your third suggestion)?

Comment: I think this is the worst possibility, but I added an example.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to MrBean Bremen excellent answer, I also found another solution:
Add a fixture in the script file, which returns the sting - then use the request.getfixturevalue() function in the conf_test.py file.

my_script1.py:

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture(scope='module')
def my_var:
    return 'This string will be used in the module fixture'

test_first():
    # Do stuff
```

conf_test.py:

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture(scope='module', autouse=True)
def script_handler():
    txt = request.getfixturevalue('my_var')
    # Use txt
    yield
```